# IP leaking from VPN services

Tags: vpn, ip, webrtc

I'm looking to buy a simple VPN service (let's say from NordVPN, or any other popular VPN company really) to only occasionally protect my internet activity.

Most of the time (e.g., when casual browsing) it will be turned off to achieve higher speeds and when privacy is important, only then will it be turned on. So, every now and then it will be switching on/off.

I read something about IP leaking (and WebRTC etc.) and how a VPN might sometimes not work, and a less tech-savvy user (like me) might not even notice.

If I go to my device's network settings, take note of the IP my ISP normally assigns to me (without a VPN obviously), then turn on my VPN and see the IP has now changed, shouldn't that be proof to me that my VPN is in fact working as it should?

Is there anything else that I should do to make sure it's working?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the IP is useful to check if the VPN is up, but its not fullproof - there may be some routes which still don't go via the VPN. Probably the most important one to watch out relates to DNS.

Routers often proxy DNS and act as local name servers - and the link between you and your router and computer can't go through the VPN. This will allow DNS queries to leak back to your ISP.

Less of a problem, It is likewise possible for programs/services running on your PC to bind to particular interfaces or discover non-vpn ip's which can be correlated against your VPN and expose you in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I said, I'm less tech savvy, so I'm not aware of DNS, yet. I'll google it. By the way, when I download (let's say) NordVPN's app, and click to turn it on, does it automatically turn on system-wide, or just for specific programs only (like a browser or a torrent downloader)? If the latter, then how does one set it up to work system-wide? (I'd suspect setting it up through the router, maybe?)

Comment: I have never used nordvpn, but I believe it uses openvpn under the hood.  I expect that pretty much any VPN software will, by default, be system wide - I know openvpn is.  It sets it up on the device it runs on - so if run on a PC it protects the PC. Setting it up on a router requires a router that supports the VPN and is more work. (Setting it up on a router protects the entire network. But is not something you would typically toggle on and off)